# What does .transform() exactly do in sklearn StandardScaler?

Tags: scikit-learn

I am studying StandardScaler right now. However, I do not understand what does .transform exactly do. In API document, it just say "Perform standardization by centering and scaling" Can someone explain?

Answer (score 3):

The standard scaler function has formula:

```
z = (x - u) / s
```

Here,

```
x: Element  
u: Mean  
s: Standard Deviation
```

This element transformation is done column-wise.
Therefore, when you call to fit the values of `mean` and `standard_deviation` are calculated.

Eg:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randint(50,size = (10,2))
x
```

Output:

```
array([[26,  9],
       [29, 39],
       [23, 26],
       [29, 22],
       [28, 41],
       [11,  6],
       [42, 40],
       [ 1, 25],
       [ 0, 39],
       [44, 45]])
```

Now, fitting the standard scaler

```
scale = StandardScaler()
scale.fit(x)
```

You can see the mean and standard deviation using the built methods for the `StandardScaler` object

```
# Mean
scale.mean_   # array([23.3, 29.2])

# Standard Deviation
scale.scale_  # array([14.36697602, 13.12859475])
```

You transform these values using the transform method.

```
scale.transform(x)
```

Output:

```
array([[ 0.18793099, -1.53862621],
       [ 0.3967432 ,  0.74646222],
       [-0.02088122, -0.24374277],
       [ 0.3967432 , -0.54842122],
       [ 0.32713913,  0.89880145],
       [-0.85613006, -1.76713506],
       [ 1.3015961 ,  0.82263184],
       [-1.55217075, -0.31991238],
       [-1.62177482,  0.74646222],
       [ 1.44080424,  1.20347991]])
```

Calculation for 1st element:

```
z = (26 - 23.3) /  14.36697602
z = 0.18793099
```

Answer (score 1):

If you click on `[source]` on the right side you can see the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf3/sklearn/preprocessing/_data.py#L778). From lines 796 to 807 you'll see

```
if sparse.issparse(X):
    if self.with_mean:
        raise ValueError(
            "Cannot center sparse matrices: pass `with_mean=False` "
            "instead. See docstring for motivation and alternatives.")
    if self.scale_ is not None:
        inplace_column_scale(X, 1 / self.scale_)
else:
    if self.with_mean:
        X -= self.mean_
    if self.with_std:
        X /= self.scale_
```

You can see that it performs standardization in the if-else block.